# Jquery if statement with two class conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some difficulties with a jQuery `if` statement.  The logic that I am trying to test for is"

"If an airport's elevation is greater than 1000 **AND** the `temp_f` is less than 32, show the "ice" div in the "warnings" column for that airport."

There is corresponding HTML and CSS for this question, but I will leave that part out, unless it is needed.

In this case:

- the airports elevation is tagged with the "elevation" class
- the airport's temperature is tagged with the "temp_f" class
- "ice" is a hidden div under the "warnings" table header (`th`)
- all are within a table row

Using my logic, I wrote the code:

```
$("td.elevation, td.temp_f").each(function() {
    if (($("td.elevation").text() > 1000) && $("td.temp_f").text() < 32)) {
        $("div.ice").show()
    }
});
```

However, the code above and several other variants have not worked at all. I am so stuck.

Comment: please use a code linter either in an IDE or online to help fix syntax errors. Questions like this don't belong here and have no long term value for anyone else

Answer (score 2):

...because you wrote `funciton` instead of `function`?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `$$`, instead of `&&`

Answer (score 1):

There were few bugs in your code and I bet that this `"temp_f"` should be without the quotation marks, because it's a variable, isn't it?

```js
$("td.elevation").each(function() {
   if (($(this).text() > 100) && (temp_f < 32)) {
     $("div.ice").show();
   }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `each(funciton() {` should be `each(function() {`.
2. It's `&&` not `$$`
3. `"temp_f" < 32` has no meaning. If you have a variable named `temp_f` then you should compare it like this: `temp_f < 32`.